# How to remove zero values labels using chartjs-plugins-datalabels

Tags: chart.js

To show the value on the bar chart, I'm using chartjs-plugins-datalabels. However, my data consists a lot of zeros thus it cause the charts looks messy. I can't define the zeros to 'null/undefined' because it need to be used. How can I remove the value label for `[0]` using chartjs-plugins-datalabels without redefine the zeros?

[My bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXdwf.png)

Here is the code for datalabels:

```
plugins:{
    datalabels: {
    align: 'end',
    anchor: 'end'
    },
 },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `formatter` as shown below. The function returns an empty string if the value is zero, the value itself otherwise.

```
plugins:{
  datalabels: {
    align: 'end',
    anchor: 'end',
    formatter: v => v ? v : ''
  }
}
```

> For further details, please consult [Custom Labels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/formatting.html#custom-labels) from the `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Change zeros to **undefined** or **null**

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. However, I need to use the zero data in other place. Is it possible to only remove the labels using chartjs-plugins-datalabels?